# Kotlin: "if item not in list" proper syntax

Tags: kotlin

Given Kotlin's list lookup syntax,

```
if (x in myList)
```

as opposed to idiomatic Java,

```
if (myList.contains(x))
```

how can one express negation?  The compiler doesn't like either of these:

```
if (x not in mylist)

if !(x in mylist)
```

Is there an idiomatic way to express this other than `if !(mylist.contains(x)))`?  I didn't see it mentioned in the [Kotlin Control Flow docs.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Use `x !in list` syntax.

The following code:

```
val arr = intArrayOf(1,2,3)
if (2 !in arr)
   println("in list")
```

is compiled down to the equivalent of:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
// uses xor since JVM treats booleans as int
if(ArraysKt.contains(arr, 2) ^ true) { 
   System.out.println("in list");
}
```

The `in` and `!in` operators use any accessible method or extension method that is named `contains` and returns `Boolean`. For a collection (list, set...) , it uses `collection.contains` method. For arrays (including primitive arrays) it uses the extension method `Array.contains` which is implemented as `indexOf(element) >= 0`

Comment: Thank you for this

Comment: @AdamHughes Also, it is the same for `is`-check: its negation is `!is`.

Answer (score 29):

The operator for this in Kotlin is `!in`. So you can do

```
if (x !in myList) { ... }
```

You can find this in the official docs about [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#binary-operations).

Comment: Ah, I never saw this operator overloading doc, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### !in with matching data classes

Although `==` will compare duplicated data classes as equal, `!in` doesn't consider duplicate copies to be the same.

Here is my solution:

```
// Create a set of hashcodes
val itemHashes = myCollection.map { it.hashCode() }.toSet()

// Use !in with the set
item.hashCode() !in itemHashes

// For comparing a whole collection
myCollection.filter { it.hashCode() !in itemHashes }
```

Answer (score -4):

```
if (myList!!.contains(x)){

    }

if (!myList!!.contains(x)){

    }
```